# Receive data from the backend

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, fetch

I have written code in React JS that receives data from a backend. This backend connects to a database.

I receive this data using axios, but I get this error: "data.map is not a function ( **react.js - express.js - MongoDB **)".

I have a card component using props that calls only two data (**name & image**)

I receive them in the console and I have used **Cors **in the backend

npm i cors/  const cors  = require('cors')  /   app.use(cors())

## Page Gallery

```
import {useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CardSmall from '../Components/CardSmall';

const Gallery = () => {
    const [ data , setData ] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/items/")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data); 
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);
  



  return (
    <div className='w-100 vh-100'>
        <h1>Gallery</h1>

        

        <div style={{width:'90%', margin:'auto',display:'flex', flexWrap:'wrap', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          {
            data.map(item => <CardSmall key={item._id} {...item} />)
          }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Gallery
```

## Card component: I expected it to show the data one after the other in separate cards.

Before, I could display the data, but I created the data using a fake server (**json-server**).

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

function CardSmall({name , image}) {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} >
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} alt={name} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
        <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default CardSmall;
```

Comment: What is `console.log(res.data)` printing?

Answer (score 0):

Since component gets rendered before useEffect, you are getting this error.
To overcome this have a condition on data

```
{data.length
? data.map(item => <CardSmall key={item._id} {...item} />)
:null // you can have loader
}
```